# What is the formula for how a force affects linear motion on a rigid body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, collision, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

Say a body (two glued spheres will do) hits a ceiling, and the balls and ceiling are the only things in the universe. I translate the point of impact to the center of mass, calculate my lever arms, and then the sine between these arms and the $y$ force on the rigid body. From that I get the torque, and divide that torque by the moment of inertia to get the angular accelerations $x$ and $z$.
How do I calculate the linear acceleration? I've been reading about "a force applied to a point on the rigid body is like as if the force was applied to the center of mass", but it doesnt 'feel' that if my body collided when a ball was exactly above the other, it would recoil the same way as if they were at an angle. I don't even know what to think if BOTH balls collided at the same time...
But I might be "feeling" wrong, and the acceleration would always be Force/Mass, no matter what angle my body came in? In other words, if the assembly came in with velocity Vy, it always leaves with velocity -Vy, but probable different rotations? Because this would make linear response and torque completely independent - and wonderful.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to dynamics human intuition is often wrong. What is important is the mathematical modeling and the story it tells you in each situation.

Consider the following points

- Newton's 2nd *law* always applies to point masses, as well as rigid bodies.
- The net force on the body defines the rate of change of momentum $$ \vec{F}_{\rm net} = \tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \vec{p} $$
- Momentum is *always* defined as the product of total mass $m$ and the velocity of the center of mass $\vec{v}_{\rm cm}$ $$\vec{p} = m \,\vec{v}_{\rm cm}$$
- Newton's 2nd law thus takes the familiar form describing the motion of the center of mass $$\vec{F}_{\rm net} = m \, \vec{a}_{\rm cm} $$
- When it comes to impacts, then the impulse form of Newton's 2nd law is $$ \vec{J} = m \Delta \vec{v}_{\rm cm} $$ where $\vec{J}$ is some impulse acting on a body. An impulse is the area under the force-vs-time curve $J = \int F {\rm d}t$
- There is a rotational equivalent called the Euler's equations of motion

  $$ \vec{\tau}_{\rm cm} = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{L}_{\rm cm} $$ where $\vec{\tau}_{\rm cm}$ is the net torque applied on a body measured about the center of mass, and $\vec{L}_{\rm cm}$ is the angular momentum of the body summed about the center of mass also.
- Angular momentum is often decomposed based on the mass moment of inertia tensor into $$\vec{L}_{\rm cm} = {\rm I}_{\rm cm}\; \vec{\omega} $$ where ${\rm I}_{\rm cm}$ is the MMOI tensor about the center of mass and $\vec{\omega}$ is the rotational velocity of the body
- This leads to the differential form of the equations of motion $$ \vec{\tau}_{\rm cm} = {\rm I}_{\rm cm} \vec{\alpha} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{L}_{\rm cm}$$
- And the impulse-based equations $$ \vec{r} \times \vec{J} = {\rm I}_{\rm cm} \Delta \vec{\omega} $$  where $\vec{r}$ is the location of the impulse relative to the center of mass.
- Going back to your "feeling" what you are trying to describe is the resulting change in motion of a specific point (not the center of mass) when an impulse is applied at that point.

  See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/794070/392 where I go into more details on how to quantify such feeling with the concepts of the effective mass at a point.